# Netapp RSH Failing

Tags: netapp, rsh

I have two NetApp Filers that are part of a cluster (Version 7.1.3).

I'm able to connect to one of the filers via RSH fine, but the second filer is failing with this error:

```
[rshd_0:info]: couldn't connect second port
```

I've rebooted the filer and checked the settings. The routing table looks to be corrupted but I can't tell if this would case this problem:

```
192.91           link#2             UC          0        0  e4
192.91.107.1     link#2             UHL         1        0  e4
```

Is the routing table related to RSH failing or is there something else I could check in the settings?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a corrupted routing table, don't worry about it. Because of the way CIDR works, 192.91 is the same as 192.91.0.0 - you can check for basic connectivity via e.g. ping. If you can ping it, it's fine.

More likely, `rsh` is turned off on your filer - that's considered a good thing, as `rsh` is an old and insecure protocol.

Check `options rsh` and see what `rsh.access` and `rsh.enable` are set to.

But consider actually just stopping using `rsh` entirely, and switch to `ssh` - with public-private key pairs - for filer admin tasks like this.